# Xamarin.iOS : MTOUCH: error MT4109: Failed to compile the generated registrar code

Tags: ios, xamarin

I cannot build a Xamarin.iOS app with the iOS 11.0 sdk, Xcode-beta 9.0. I am about to release and have got this error in Release/IPhone mode. I'm using alpha version of Xamarin.iOS framework. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance. Here is the output:

---

MTOUCH: error MT4109: Failed to compile the generated registrar code. Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com
    Task "MTouch" execution -- FAILED
    Done building target "_CompileToNative" in project "/Users/Developer/Desktop/PROJECT/OTP/iOS/OTP.iOS.csproj".-- FAILED

Done building project "/Users/Developer/Desktop/PROJECT/OTP/iOS/OTP.iOS.csproj".-- FAILED

Build FAILED.

Warnings:

/Users/Developer/Desktop/PROJECT/OTP/iOS/OTP.iOS.csproj (Build) ->
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.0/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets (ResolveAssemblyReferences target) ->

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.0/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'SQLiteNetExtensions' not resolved
```

Errors:

/Users/Developer/Desktop/PROJECT/OTP_v2.0.3-ImageProblem/iOS/OTP.iOS.csproj (Build) ->
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets (_CompileToNative target) ->

```
MTOUCH: error MT4109: Failed to compile the generated registrar code. Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

 1 Warning(s)
 1 Error(s)
```

Time Elapsed 00:01:03.1991100

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build configurations:  [SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgoTK.png)

Comment: First of all you can't release the app with Xcode beta. Second, you can do that with Xamarin beta but I don't think that any professional would do that. So wait for the updates to come in next week or two. Even if you resolve this problem, just don't do that.

Comment: Ooh, right. Thanks a lot. Also, with Xamarin beta, do you mean that I can change the update channel to beta and compile in release? I'm just asking.

Comment: It's broken with the release version of Xcode as well...

Comment: After Xamarin.iOS stable update there isnt any problem anymore.